# Dockerで作成したUbuntuの環境でESCがうまく働かず、Vimが抜けられない

Tags: ubuntu, vim, docker

Dockerで作成したUbuntuでvimコマンドを使いたいのですが、
escキーを押すと^[というのが出てくるばかりで、モードの切り替えができません。
[image: ESCを押すと^[が出てくる]

環境は以下の通りです。
ホスト：macOS
コンテナ：Ubuntu 14.04
Vimのインストール：apt-get install -y sudo vim

何かわかる方がいれば教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

Dockerコンテナの実行時に-tオプションをつけていないのが原因でした。
`docker run -it ubuntu_test`
こんな感じで大丈夫でした